# .slick height incorrect adaptiveheight

Tags: height, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to get all elements in the carousel to be one height.. I took out adaptive height from the source code but it didn't fix it

```
 // Homepage Carousel
      $('.homepage-carousel').slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        //adaptiveheight: true,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>',
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1400,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1000,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      });
```

website live here: raginiacrossthepond.blogspot.com

Comment: double check the html & css of the elements to ensure there isn't differing padding, margins, height settings that may be pushing the alignment off

Comment: is this not the html/css of these elements?

Comment: what is your html code? was the output of different height initially?